# Change a commit author in NetBeans

Tags: git, netbeans

I'm working with a Git repository in NetBeans, and I accidentally messed up and wrote a commit with the wrong username/email attached to it. I'd like to change this before I push to GitHub. How can I do this?

Comment: @ColonelPanic - I want to know how to change a commit author in NetBeans, which is different from reverting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-do-i-change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git

Answer (score 0):

@Nathan2055 - have a look at GitHub [change author info](http://web.archive.org/web/20180604120659/http://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/). I believe this cannot be done from within NetBeans itself.

Comment: Can I simply delete the commit either in NetBeans or on my hard drive?

Comment: You can go with `git reset --soft HEAD^` one step back, just to the point before you commit the changes.
see also (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) under "Undo a commit and redo"